# Snippits: error while trying to run ks do

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'd quite like to use Snippits, but after I carefully followed these directions:

http://lifehacker.com/351285/automate-repetitive-typing-with-snippits

I tried using the keyboard shortcut I'd assigned to Snippits and got the error:

"Error while trying to run (ks do)"

I've looked around, and it seems to be a common problem, but I haven't had any luck finding an answer. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: Update: I wrote the author, and unfortunately he isn't maintaining Snippits anymore. He recommends: "Check out AutoKey (http://code.google.com/p/autokey) or IronAHK
(https://github.com/polyethene/IronAHK)"

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this error means that the program 'ks' is not installed, and it is not a recognized command.

When I had this issue it was a result of the snippits not being installed due to error.  When executing the line:

```
sudo gem install snippits
```

I received this error (which I didn't notice because I was just copy and pasting):

```
hoe requires RubyGems version >= 1.4
```

In order to update RubyGems I executed this line:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

After updating RubyGems I was able to successfully install snippits:

```
   sudo gem install snippits
```

Now the ks command will be recognized.